# Programmatically Quit Qt Installer Framework

Tags: qt, installation

I have an installer written with QTIFW, it has a custom dynamic page that asks the user for a key, and verifies that it's valid. If invalid, installation is prevented.

I want to do a similar thing, but for an unattended/CLI install. e.g.

```
myinstaller.exe --accept-licenses install Key=<InstallKey>
```

How can I gracefully exit the installer using a component or controller script? The only way I've found to do this is by throwing an exception in `function Component()`